# get all the elements of a particular form

Tags: javascript

```
function getInputElements() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
}
```

The above code gets all the `input` elements on a page which has more than one form. How do I get the `input` elements of a particular form using plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
document.forms["form_name"].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Comment: as long as there are no selects or textareas ;-)

Comment: Can you show it in a case use application with several inputs with values that it's grabbing?

Comment: I prefer `document.forms["form_name"].getElementByClassName("myClass")`

Comment: Typo in getElementsByClassName: `document.forms["form_name"].getElementsByClassName("myClass")`

Comment: This will also not match any form elements that live outside the form in the DOM but are part of it using their `form` attribute.

Answer (score 168):

```
document.getElementById("someFormId").elements;
```

This collection will also contain `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements ([among others](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements#Value)), but you probably want that.

Comment: It appears that document.getElementById("someFormId") also works. Any particular reason for adding .elements at the end?

Comment: @Andrew: My intention was that "someFormId" is the ID of a `<form>` element, not an input. `elements` is a property of a form element; it's a collection of elements within the form. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements

Comment: > ok, i understand what .elements is. So should I use it, if it works even without it? Maybe adding .elements selects less nodes and thus you get better performance?

Comment: @Andrew: Works how? You can access form inputs by name as properties of the form but there are problems with that: first, the form has other properties that could potentially clash (for example, an input with name "action" would not be reflected as a property of the form because the form already has an `action` property that reflects its `action` attribute). Second, there is no easy, reliable way to enumerate the inputs as properties of the form object and certainly not in order. `elements` has numeric properties in document order in addition to the properties corresponding to input names.

Comment: Thanks, i think you are right. It's better to select with .elements

Comment: how to filter the inputs from that list

Answer (score 24):

You're all concentrating on the word 'get' in the question. Try the 'elements' property of any form which is a collection that you can iterate through i.e. you write your own 'get' function.

Example:

```
function getFormElelemets(formName){
  var elements = document.forms[formName].elements;
  for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    some code...
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) if you want the values:

```
var form = document.getElementById('form-name');
var data = new FormData(form);
for (var [key, value] of data) {
    console.log(key, value)
}
```

Comment: Note that `FormData` won't contain disabled or unchecked elements.

Comment: You are right, @FarzadYousefzadeh. But we also must remember that disabled and unchecked elements are not sent when submitting a form conventionally.

Comment: Is there something opposite to FormData? That is, from an object to copy the values ​​to the inputs?

Comment: Not directly, @Antonito. You should write a piece of Javascript to do that. While it is not hard, it deserves a new question in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11):

It is also possible to use this:

```
var user_name    = document.forms[0].elements[0];
var user_email   = document.forms[0].elements[1];
var user_message = document.forms[0].elements[2];
```

All the elements of forms are stored in an array by Javascript. This takes the elements from the first form and stores each value into a unique variable.

Answer (score 11):

## First, get all the elements

```
const getAllFormElements = element => Array.from(element.elements).filter(tag => ["select", "textarea", "input"].includes(tag.tagName.toLowerCase()));
```

### Second, do something with them

```
const pageFormElements = getAllFormElements(document.body);
console.log(pageFormElements);
```

#### If you want to use a form, rather than the entire body of the page, you can do it like this

```
const pageFormElements = getAllFormElements(document.getElementById("my-form"));
console.log(formElements);
```

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't been upvoted.  Very concise method to get all the form elements, including selects and text areas of a specific form.

Comment: Thank you very much!! <3

Comment: This one neatly includes relevant values (of inputs (text, number, radios, checks), selects and textareas) but excludes e.g. buttons. Sweet.

Answer (score 9):

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("formId").getElementsByTagName("input");
var inputs = document.forms[1].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Update for 2020:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#formId input");
```

Answer (score 8):

Loosely relevant but if you'd like to get all of the form items in an object you can:

```
Object.fromEntries(new FormData(document.querySelector('form')).entries())
```

Which yields

```
{
   email: "thao@le.com",
   password: "mypassword"
}
```

Comment: Note that `FormData` won't contain disabled or unchecked elements. –

Answer (score 7):

SIMPLE Form code

```
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="User" value="Arsalan"/>
        <input type="password" name="pass" value="123"/>
        <input type="number" name="age" value="24"/>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="johndoe@test.com"/>
        <textarea name="message">Enter Your Message Her</textarea>

    </form>
```

Javascript Code

```
//Assign Form by Id to a Variabe
    var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
    //Extract Each Element Value
    for (var i = 0; i < myForm.elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(myForm.elements[i].value);
    }
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/rng0hpss/

Comment: it will return [array of `input` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements), except `type="image"`

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
var theForm = document.forms['formname']
[].slice.call(theForm).forEach(function (el, i) {
    console.log(el.value);
});
```

The el stands for the particular form element. It is better to use this than the foreach loop, as the foreach loop also returns a function as one of the element. However this only returns the DOM elements of the form.

Comment: Hey, Here what is happening I tried to return if the id matches to a value then it should return which will break the loop and will return the result. But it is not doing such thing.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate unfortunately it is not possible to stop the slice foreah loop with a break or return, however there is a work around by throwing and catching an exception. Once you find the element you are looking for, you throw and exception to break out of the loop, then catch it so as not to cause any error.

 try{
  [].slice.call(theForm).forEach(function (el, i){
   console.log(el.id);
   if (el.id == 'e2') throw new Exception;
  });
 }catch(err){ }

Again, if you know the id of the element you are looking for, why not just select it directly rather than going through a loop

Answer (score 5):

Try this to get all the form fields.

```
var fields = document['formName'].elements;
```

Comment: This is honestly the best answer as it doesn't use the other (relatively slower) lookups.

Comment: It also allows looking up fields by name, e.g. `fields.title` for whichever input element has `name="title"`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a reference to any field in the form or an event then you don't need to explicitly look up the form since every form field has a `form` attribute that points to its parent form (if there is one, of course). That means that once you have a field reference to a DOM element `userName` then `userName.form` will be the form. If `$userName` is a jQuery object, then `$userName.get(0).form` will give you the form.

If you have an event then it will contain a `target` attribute which will point to the form field that triggered the event, which means you can access the form via `myEvent.target.form`.

Here is an example without any form lookup code.

```js
function doLogin(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // e.target is the submit button
    var form = e.target.form;

    if (form.login.value && form.password.value) {
        alert("Submitting form — user:" + form.login.value + " password:" + form.password.value);
        form.submit();
    } else {
        alert('Please fill in the form!');
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <form name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="login"><br />
        <input type="password" name="password"><br />
        <button type="submit" onclick="doLogin()">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

> If you have multiple forms on the page you still don't need to label them by name or id, because you'll always get the correct form instance via the event or via a reference to a field.

Answer (score 3):

You can select by simply taking all elements that contain the attribute `name`

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form");

form.querySelectorAll("[name]");
```

This will return all relevant elements of the form.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want form elements that have a `name` attribute, you can filter the form elements.

```
const form = document.querySelector("your-form")
Array.from(form.elements).filter(e => e.getAttribute("name"))
```

Answer (score 1):

How would you like to differentiate between forms? You can use different IDs, and then use this function:

```
function getInputElements(formId) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formId);
    if (form === null) {
        return null;
    }
    return form.getElementsByTagName('input');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let formFields     = form.querySelectorAll(`input:not([type='hidden']), select`)
```

ES6 version that has the advantage of ignoring the hidden fields if that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

I could have sworn there used to be a convenient `fields` property on a form but … Must have been my imagination.

I just do this (for `<form name="my_form"></form>`) because I usually don't want fieldsets themselves:

```
let fields = Array.from(document.forms.my_form.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const contactForm = new FormData("formLocatorIdIsAdviceableAsTheLocator");
```

The above is handy regardless of context(framework or pure js because):

1. It returns you an object using the form input-names as keys and the element-value as value
2. You can add your own object:
   contactForm.append(yourKey,yourValye)

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData