# Javascript how to get all element of a form

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a line of javascript code that works perfect in IE

```
document.forms[0].all
```

what it does, it gets all the dom elements including **their child elements**.

I want this same in chrome, i used this:

```
document.forms[0].childNodes
```

what it does, It gets all the dom elements **but not their childs**

So, my question is how to achieve the same functionality for chrome?

Thanks

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: No, i cannot use JQuery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4431162/20126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('*')
```

or

```
document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('*')
```

This won't give you text nodes, but DOM elements you will get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
document.forms[0].children
```

You can iterate child elements with

```
document.forms[0].children[i]
```