# I want to access the input block created by user using javascript code

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add(element){
 var form = window.document.dynamicForm;
 // We clone the add button
 var add = element.cloneNode(true);
 // Create a new HTML tag of type "input"'

   my_form=document.createElement('FORM');
   my_form.name='myForm';


//var field = document.createElement("input");

 // The value filled in the form will be stored in an array
// field.name = "champs[]";
// field.placeholder = "champs[input]";
// field.type = "text";
//MAIN DOCUMENTATION

my_tb=document.createElement('INPUT');
my_tb.type='TEXT';
my_tb.name='myInput';
my_tb.placeholder='Values of my Input';
my_form.appendChild(my_tb);

my_tb1=document.createElement('INPUT');
my_tb1.type='text';
my_tb1.name='myInput1';
my_tb1.placeholder='Values of my hidden1';
my_form.appendChild(my_tb1);

my_tb2=document.createElement('INPUT');
my_tb2.type='text';
my_tb2.name='myInput2';
my_tb2.placeholder='Values of my hidden1';
my_form.appendChild(my_tb2); 

document.body.appendChild(my_form);

 var rem = document.createElement("input");
 rem.value = "Remove a field";
 rem.type = "button";
 // Add the onclick event
 rem.onclick = function onclick(event)
  {del(this);};

 // We create a new element of type "p" and we insert the field inside.
 var bloc = document.createElement("p");
 bloc.appendChild(field);
 //form.insertBefore(add, element);
 //form.insertBefore(rem, element);
 form.insertBefore(bloc, element);}
```

**Sir Thanks in advance .sir here i want to access the input given by the user in every input block .if user increase the number of input block the i can get the input text in new block and send that to my php file which store that data into database .
please help me to access the new and created input blocks by user on clicking add column**

Comment: Why are you creating a new form everytime add() is invoked?

Comment: since you are using php you can directly use post method by which you can access all the form input by their name

Answer (score 0):

```
document.forms["form_name"].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

refer [get all the elements of a particular form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431162/get-all-the-elements-of-a-particular-form)

Comment: Sir please help to understand how can i use you suggested code in php to save all data given by every new input block in database

Comment: Plaese don't confuse js and php , You can use post method to connect to php,whatever be the input check https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Thanku for your reply sir . but i am not confusing in js and php for save the data in database but i confusing in when user increase the number of tables and the give the input in each table differently then how i get the input and save in database . please  sir help me

Comment: are you using ajax in this case

Comment: NO sir i am using Simple Javascript and XAMPP server for database